# While building a pipeline in azure for python code getting an error as ##[error]Bash exited with code '1' attaching error image

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, dependencies

## Getting an error while building a pipeline in azure for python code. Its related to dependencies.
Starting: Install dependencies

## Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.182.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line

Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/62a095aa-de7c-4922-a5a6-4160fd1ff813.sh
/home/vsts/work/_temp/62a095aa-de7c-4922-a5a6-4160fd1ff813.sh: line 1: -: command not found
display: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/426.
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Install dependencies

Comment: Hi @kedar, how are things going? Does the same Bash script can work on your local machine? Please have a try with it on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the same Bash script on your local machine to see if it can work. If it also does not work on your local, I'm afraid that the issue is no the script itself. You need to check if there is any syntax error in the script.

If the script can work fine on your local, for us to investigate this issue further, please share us with the details of the Bash script and the completed debug logs of the failed build pipeline run.